# WSO2-AM 3.1.0 - Load Balanced Endpoints not being added

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have configured two WSO2AM nodes on All in One HA deployment config. Both nodes are working fine, if we add an API on node 1, node 2 also display the API. We use IS as KM and it is on HA too.

Actually we are having issues when we try to configure Load Balanced endpoints on APIs. We add it in the API, but after save changes endpoints are not configured.
Please find below the screenshots. First screenshot is during load balanced endpoint configuration. Second screenshot is after changes saved.

**First Image**
[image: First Image]

**Second Image**
[image: Second Image]

As you can see finally the endpoint is not configured or just not saved. On the image endpoint figures out "node1" but it is correctly configured as an http node.

Below are the logs of WSO2AM node (wso2carbon.log)

```
TID: [-1234] [AuthenticationAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:51,723]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-08 13:21:51,723-0300]
TID: [-1234] [AuthenticationAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,093]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-08 13:21:52,093-0300]
TID: [-1234] [AuthenticationAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,196]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-08 13:21:52,196-0300]
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,587]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} - Destroying API: admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,592]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - API : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado was removed from the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,595]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} - Destroying API: admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,597]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - API : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1 was removed from the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,628]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Sequence : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1--Fault was  removed from the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,655]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Sequence : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1--Out was  removed from the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,656]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Sequence : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1--In was  removed from the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,659]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Local entry : 97617dba-2d20-43ff-a263-ae54d357d238 was removed from the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,659] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.localentry.service.LocalEntryAdmin} - Entry with the key 97617dba-2d20-43ff-a263-ae54d357d238 does not exist
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,662]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Local entry : 97617dba-2d20-43ff-a263-ae54d357d238 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,666]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Endpoint : mdrestsolicitudnominado--v1_APIproductionEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,669]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Endpoint : mdrestsolicitudnominado--v1_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,726]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Sequence : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1--Fault was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,734]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Sequence : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1--Out was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,754]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - Sequence : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1--In was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,762]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - API : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,763]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} - Initializing API: admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado:v1
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,773]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} - API : admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado was added to the Synapse configuration successfully
TID: [-1234] [APIGatewayAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,773]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} - Initializing API: admin--mdrestsolicitudnominado
TID: [-1234] [AuthenticationAdmin] [2020-06-08 13:21:52,814]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2020-06-08 13:21:52,814-0300]
TID: [-1] [] [2020-06-08 13:21:53,059]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected
TID: [-1] [] [2020-06-08 13:21:53,062]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.DataBridge} - user admin connected
```

Why this can be happening? I checked another logs and nothig special there.

Please if you need further information, just let me know

Comment: Click the + button in the loadbalance endpoint text box to add the endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to click on the + button in the input box to add the loadbalance or fail over endpoints.

Comment: Yes! That was my complete mistake! I just discovered it and a few minutes later you answer the question. Do you know if I have to add again both endpoints or just one and it will balance between the first configured and the load balanced?
Thanks!

Comment: The added loadbalance endpoints (Production or Sandbox) with be in the same group with the respective original endpoint. So, no need to add the original endpoint again.